# How to swap array of characters (in-place) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, reverse

So basically without being able / permitted to make a new array. An not being able to returning anything but actually changing and manipulating the current array. How do you take an array of characters and simply flip / reverse them.

```
Starting array: ['P','e','r','f','e','c','t',' ','M','a','k','e','s',' ','P','r','a','c','t','i','c','e']
```

**Reverse back each word separate by space**

```
Reversed: ['P','r','a','c','t','i','c','e',' ','M','a','k','e','s',' ','P','e','r','f','e','c','t']
```

This is what I have so far

**Code:**

```
  class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       char[] charArr = new char[] {'P','e','r','f','e','c','t',' ','M','a','k','e','s',' ','P','r','a','c','t','i','c','e'};
       reverseCharArray(charArr);
     }


     public static void reverseCharArray() {
       int arrLength = charArr.length;
       for (int i = 0; i <= arrLength / 2; i++) {
         charArr[arrLength - i - 1] = charArr[i];
         System.out.println(charArr);
       }
     }
   }
```

**Update:
Ok what I have found is that. What I need to do is actually swap the words the sentence of characters spell. So that the sentence is backwards / reversed.**

**Note: This was attempted in a online interview here:
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/aotBpjJUqJo)**

Comment: there are a number of problems here. First you will lose data because you are overwriting data in your char array and not actually swapping. Secondly you are reversing the whole char array. In your example you reverse the full words not the chars.

Comment: @Hunter do you want to swap two intervals or reverse the whole array?

Comment: reverse the whole array @IvanKukic

Comment: @Hunter your example input/output suggests you swapped only some of the chars in the array, `'M', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's'` wasn't moved at all.

Comment: if you reverse the whole array, you'll get `['e','c','i','t','c','a','r','P',' ','s','e','k','a','M',' ','t','c','e','f','r','e','P']`, not what's in the question

Comment: Oh ok dang well then it must be swap to Intervals then @Kaddath

Comment: The simplest would really to use another temporary array, is it a code challenge or homeworks so that you're not allowed to?

Comment: Yea just a code challenge I guess. I saw someone try to attempted it a couple days ago. @Kaddath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely not a good solution, but it's a working one.

```
class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] charArr = new char[] { 'P', 'e', 'r', 'f', 'e', 'c', 't', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' ', 'P', 'r',
            'a', 'c', 't', 'i', 'c', 'e' };
    System.out.println(charArr);
    reverseCharArray(charArr,0);
    System.out.println(charArr);
}


public static void reverseCharArray(char[] charArr, int sorted) {


    /* Look for last space*/
    int lastSpace = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) { 
        if (charArr[i] == ' ') {
            lastSpace = i; 
        }
    }

    /* Grab the word and move it at the beginning of the sorted array */
    for (int i = lastSpace + 1; i < charArr.length; i++) {

        int k = i;

        while (k != sorted) {
            char tmp = charArr[k-1];
            charArr[k-1] = charArr[k];
            charArr[k] = tmp;
            k--;
        }

        sorted++;
    }


    /* At this point, the last character is a space*/
    /* Else, we've swapped all the words */
    int k = charArr.length - 1;
    if (charArr[k] != ' ') {
        return;
    }

    /* If it's a space, grab it and move it at the beginning*/
    while (k != sorted) {
        char tmp = charArr[k-1];
        charArr[k-1] = charArr[k];
        charArr[k] = tmp;
        k--;
    }
    sorted++;


    /*Recursive call on the not sorted array*/
    reverseCharArray(charArr,sorted);

}}
```

Comment: wow it does actually work it swaps the sentence to say Practice makes perfect! An by the way it is the only solution on here that successfully does so, by the way Nice Job!

Answer (score 1):

The method below swaps intervals. Note that they must be of same length.

```
public static char[] swap(char[] arr, int lstart, int rstart, int len){
      for(int i=lstart; i<lstart+len; i++){
        char temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[rstart+i];
        arr[rstart+i] = temp;
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try and test it, but what is lstart and rstart by the way?

Comment: @Hunter I fixed it now, it works. Lstart is the index of the start of the "left" interval, and "rstart" of the right interval. For example, if I had `A B C D E` and wanted to swap `AB` with `D E` I'd call the function as (arr, 0, 3 ,2). 0 - start of left interval, 3- start of right interval, 2- length of the intervals.

Comment: Oh I see so its like a rudimentary version of what Im looking for, so basically if I had 2 words that were the same length I can swap those 2

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't seem to solve your problem, after you edited in the clarification.

Comment: It's a pretty cool function though I'll up vote. It may help someone else out, who knows

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following array; `[h, e, y,  , y, o, u]` you'd have to work in a pattern; from the outside to the inside (or the other way around). so, `[1,2,3,4,3,2,1]` you'd have to swap `1` and `1`, `2` and `2` and so on. as you can see, this array has a length of 7, in this case the amount of swaps needed is exactly 4 (`4` is swapped with itsself). To calculate the amount of swaps, you can simply ceil the array length divided by `2.0f`.

Now you have to loop trough the array, swapping those indexes. To calculate which index to swap, you have to check at wich swap your are. Let's say you're at the second swap, the indexes of `2` in the array are 1 and 5, those of `3` are 2 and 4. You've probably recognized the pattern by now. The first index is always the amount of done swaps, where the second is the length of the array minus 1 minus the amount of done swaps.

here's this put into code;

```java
    public static void swap(char[] array){
        int totalSwaps = (int) Math.ceil(array.length / 2.0f);
        for(int currentSwaps = 0; currentSwaps < totalSwaps; currentSwaps++){
            char char1 = array[currentSwaps];
            int position2 = array.length - (currentSwaps + 1);
            array[currentSwaps] = array[position2];
            array[position2] = char1;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
```

**EDIT: I just saw that you were asking to reverse each word in a char[], you might want to clarify that in the first sentences**

to do this; I'd recommend you use `String::split` to split the string into a string[] and use `String::toCharArray` to change it to a character array. Though this does create new arrays

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm for this, is as follows,

1. Initially, reverse the individual words of the given string one by
   one, for the provided example `"Perfect Makes Practice"`, after reversing individual words the string should be `“tcefreP sekaM ecitcarP”`.
2. Reverse the whole string from start to end to get the desired output `"Practice Makes Perfect"` in the above example.

For more check [Reverse words in a given string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-words-in-a-given-string/).